# ContextMenu designer application in C#

Tags: c#, winforms, contextmenu

Is there any simply possibility to create application in which I can create any ContextMenu as easy as in Visual Studio like this (image below)? I mean is there any component or is already done any application with source code which can do this? I just want to be able to create some ContextMenu just items with text and icons in the application as in the VisualStudio.

[image: ContextMenu Designer]

Comment: are you looking at to create context menu at run time ?

Comment: you are already doing it....what else you want

Comment: @Turbot yep I want create context menu at runtime

Comment: What does your application do? VS has all its actions listed in the Customize menu dialog, so it must have some kind of registration mechanism for all these actions.

Comment: If you click on desktop right click - context menu will appear. And my app is adding anohter item with subitems to this menu using the context menu I've created in my app ( https://dl.dropbox.com/u/46096863/desktop_menu.png ). And I want let user create his own context menu in app. In VS its really easy and userfriendly so I want do it the same, if there is some simply possibility.

Answer (score 0):

There are several way to accomplish, my suggestion to you is to have a root **ToolStripMenuItem** in place and built a sub menu action from there.

You also need to have a dialog to *configure* how you want the action to behave accordingly.

I'm using **Process.Start** to allow user specific the actions they want to launch the application when clicking on the Sub Menu.

Here are the code snippets

```
    ToolStripMenuItem menu;

    private void InitContextMenus()
    {
      menu = new ToolStripMenuItem(">> Create Menu <<");
      menu.Click += menu_Click;
      ctMenu.Items.Add(menu);
    }

    void menu_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
      frmCreateMenu objCreateMenu = new frmCreateMenu();
      objCreateMenu.ShowDialog(this);
      if (objCreateMenu.DialogResult == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK)
      {
        ToolStripMenuItem subMenu = new ToolStripMenuItem();
        subMenu.Text = objCreateMenu.txtName.Text;
        subMenu.Click += (subSender, subEventArgs) =>
        {
          Process.Start(objCreateMenu.txtStart.Text);
        };

        menu.DropDownItems.Add(subMenu);
      }
}
```